# Place decoupling capacitor before or after the reverse voltage protection diode?

Tags: diodes, decoupling-capacitor

I want to add a reverse voltage protection diode (i'm using the 1N4001) to protect my robot from silly mistakes when connecting the battery terminals. But i also want to add a decoupling capacitor at the power supply. So, which setup should i use, A or B? And, why?

[image: reverse voltage diode]

Comment: Can your polarized cap survive reverse voltages?

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of saving the capacitor.

Comment: Make sure the diode can handle the inrush current in B

Answer (score 1):

Use B. You want the robot circuit supply to have lowest impedance. The cap's are across the circuit on B. On A, there is series impedance by the diode.

Comment: How do i prove this? What calculations can i make to show that the 2nd design would have lower impedance?

Comment: At 1mA, the "reac" of the diode will be 26 ohms. At 10mA, 2.6 ohms. At 100mA, 0.26 ohms. Thus for LOW IDDq (the MCU asleep, no stepper motor surges), the capacitor needs to be at the Load, not at the Battery. Also, if your robot has motors, you need dual power connections AT THE BATTERY, so the MCU/sensors get non-motor-spike voltage. Place 10uH and 100uF between battery and the motors.